# Netbeans C++ Weird output

Tags: c++, netbeans

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout<<"Hello World!"<<endl;
}
```

I recently installed netbeans 12.0 and when I compile the code above, it says some weird words and numbers and a letter 'H'.

Also the words `using`, `namespace`, `cout`, and `endl` are underlined and when I hover to it, it says:

> unable to resolve identifier + 'word'

This is the output:

```
PSID=1493                                                                       
NBMAGIC=1492                                                                                                                                                   
H                                                                               
RUN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 101ms)
```

Comment: I don't know Netbeans, haven't used it for over 20 years and never for C++, but it is possible that the program runs to completion, exits, and closes the console displaying the output you're expecting before you get a chance to see it.

Comment: Try adding ```system("pause");``` at the end and see if it works?

Comment: I'm a bit confused what actually happens. Does it run? Does it even compile? The errors you show seeme to be compiler errors, but you claim to get some output. Please clarify.

Comment: `system("pause")` is for suckers. Real men use a debugger breakpoint.

Comment: @churill I think the code compiles and runs, and produces the shown output. I think the keywords are being underlined by the IDE which is complaining about something.

Comment: @ProgrammingRage Thank you. It worked with `system("pause");` like what I intended to. Any idea why it only work when I put `system("pause");`?

Comment: @churill It compiles and run but it only show the letter 'H' in the phrase "Hello World".

Comment: @MathNoobie it works just fine without it, but the program runs so fast you never get to see it before it ends and takes the console with it. `system("pause")` puts your program on hold and runs a program named pause which sits and waits for the user to hit a key. When the pause program exits, your program picks up where it left off and immediately exits, closing the console window.

Comment: @user4581301 For debugging I would never use system pause. But for making the console program look progressive in nature I use system pause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @user4581301 specified that the programs runs and immediately quits so you are not able to see anything. So, we need something to pause the program.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout<<"Hello World!"<<endl;
    system("pause");
}
```